# Calling a method to check for bad input

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have this method in a class called `PersonalContact`.

```
public void validate(String name, int age, String address, String city, String state, String zip){

     //If the name field is the empty string or null, then throw a NullPointerException.
    if (name.equals(null)){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    //If the age field is not between 1-100, then throw an IllegalStateException
    if (age < 1 || age > 100){
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    //If the address or city field is the empty string or null, then throw a NullPointerException.
        if(address.equals(null) || city.equals(null)){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    //If the state field is not exactly 2 characters, then throw an IllegalStateException
        if (state.length() != 2){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    //If the zip code field is not exactly 5 numeric characters, then throw an IllegalStateException
        if (zip.length() != 5){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

    }

@Override
public void validate(String name, int age ) {


}
```

I am trying to call the method in a driver program:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlannerMain {
 static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   while (true) {

    System.out.println("Create new contact?");
    System.out.println("1.Personal contact ");
    System.out.println("2.Business Contact ");
    System.out.println("3.Exit.");

    int option = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean pcLoop = true;

    if (option == 1) { // Create Personal Contact

     do {
      try {
       validate();

       System.out.println("Name?(No spaces)");
       String name = scanner.next();

       System.out.println("Age?");
       int age = scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Address?(No Spaces)");
       String address = scanner.next();

       System.out.println("City?");
       String city = scanner.next();

       System.out.println("State?");
       String state = scanner.next();

       System.out.println("Zip");
       String zip = scanner.next();

       PersonalContact pc = new PersonalContact(name, age, address, city, state, zip);
       System.out.println(pc.toString()); // Prints out the
       // contact info
       pcLoop = false; // Ends the loop and goes back to the
       // menu
      } catch (Exception age) {
       System.out.println("Please enter name without spaces.");
      }

     } while (pcLoop); // Ends option 1

    } // End option 1
    else if (option == 2) { // Create Business Contact

     System.out.println("Name?(No spaces)");
     String name = scanner.next();

     System.out.println("Age?");
     int age = scanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Business Phone?");
     String businessPhone = scanner.next();

     System.out.println("Cellphone?");
     String cellPhone = scanner.next();

     BusinessContact bc = new BusinessContact(name, age, businessPhone, cellPhone);

     System.out.println(bc.toString());

    } // End option 2
    else if (option == 3) { /** Terminates the program */
     System.exit(0);
    } // End option 3
   } // End while

  } // End void main
} // End
```

I want the method to work with the try-catch block to catch inappropriate user input for the various fields in my PersonalContact. I want to do the same for my BusinessContact. I know I am supposed to call the method in the try block but I don't see why it's not calling it from the `PersonalContact` class and I don't understand how the exceptions will be handled with that method.

Comment: Call _pc.validate()_ once your _PersonalContact_ has been created, or make the method static .

Comment: Note: these should be `IllegalArgumentException`s, not `IllegalStateException`s. These exceptions are being caused by arguments passed to the method, not the object's state.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and what you're expecting to happen. Does this code compile? Where's your (no-arg) `validate()` method? Why aren't you calling your other `validate` methods? Shouldn't you be validating after receiving the input, not before?

Comment: `x.equals(null)` can never be true. If you want to check for null, you have to check if `x == null`.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, you haven't instantiated your object so you can't call validate on something that doesn't yet exist.
I also wanted to make a suggestion. Why don't you try putting all those validations in each of the setter methods. You can then call these from your PersonalContact's constructor. For example, inside your PersonalContact class:

```
private String name;
private int age;
...

//This should throw all the types of exceptions
//It should look like public PersonalContact(...){ throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException , etc.
public PersonalContact(name, age, address, city, state, zip){
    setName(name);
    setAge(age);
    ...
} 

public void setName(String name) throws NullPointerException {
    //If the name field is the empty string or null, then throw a NullPointerException.
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(int Age) throws IllegalStateException {
    //If the age field is not between 1-100, then throw an IllegalStateException
    if (age < 1 || age > 100){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); //as someone in the comments mentioned, use this instead of IllegalStateException
    }
    this.age = age;
}
...
```

You can keep doing these for all your other methods and by calling it from the constructor it will validate the fields when you create your object.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call in instance method until you have an instance. You need to call.

```
PersonalContact pc = new PersonalContact(name, age, address, city, state, zip);
pc.validate();
```

You then don't need to pass the validate any arguments because they are part of the state of pc. Validate should look more like this.

```
public void validate() {
     //If the name field is the empty string or null, then throw a NullPointerException.
    if (this.name == null || this.name.equals("")){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    //If the age field is not between 1-100, then throw an IllegalStateException
    if (this.age < 1 || this.age > 100){
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    //If the address or city field is the empty string or null, then throw a NullPointerException.
        if(this.address == null || this.city == null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    //If the state field is not exactly 2 characters, then throw an IllegalStateException
        if (this.state.length() != 2){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    //If the zip code field is not exactly 5 numeric characters, then throw an IllegalStateException
        if (this.zip.length() != 5){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
}
```

note that myString.equals(null) doesn't work. You have to use myString == null. Although if you are taking input from the keyboard, you are more likely to have an empty string than a null string so use myString.equals("").

If you really want to call the validate method without instantiating PersonalContact, you need to make your first validate method static and call it like

```
PersonalContact.validate(name, age, address, city, state, zip);
```

I suggest also reading up a bit on object oriented programming in general since you don't seem to have quite grasped it.